# retrieve data from SQL server depending on value of combo box in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am trying to retrieve data from a column in SQL DB depending on the value of combo box in datagridview my code is :

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs 
 {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=POSSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ms;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string priceselected = ("SELECT price FROM Table_1 WHERE name=" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(priceselected, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
 }
```

I want to put the price in `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2]`

BUT i get an sqlexception everytime I choose item from the combo box

Any help ??

Comment: kindly share your exception in details

Comment: what is the exception or error you get??

Comment: what is value in combo box?

Comment: Here are a few tips for the future: debug your code; run the sql command manually; learn about avoiding sql injection. =)

Answer (score 2):

If the data type of column `Name` is VARCHAR, you need to wrap the value with single quotes because it's a string literal.

```
string _val = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
string priceselected = ("SELECT price FROM Table_1 WHERE name='" + _val + "'");
```

but the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Please do parameterized the query,eg.

```
string _val = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
string priceselected = ("SELECT price FROM Table_1 WHERE name=@val");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(priceselected, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", _val);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: thanks very much its work , but now i want to display the value on the dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2]